# Show that $V$ is parallel iff $V'(t)$ is orthogonal to $T_\gamma(t)M$, where $V'(t)$ is the time derivative of $V$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let  $S$ be a surface in $R^3$ with induced Riemannian metric. let $\gamma
 : I\to S$
be a smooth curve on $S$ and $V$ a vector field tangent to $S$ along $\gamma$
. $V$
can be thought of as a smooth function $V : I \to R^3$
Show that $V$ is parallel if and only if $V'(t)$ is orthogonal to $T_{\gamma(t)}M$,
where $V'(t)$ is the usual time derivative of $V$ .

I know that a vector field $V$ along a curve $\gamma$ is parallel if $ \frac{DV}{dt}=0$ i.e the co variant derivative of $V$ is zero. Then I am trying to solve one direction by using the definition of $\frac{DV
}{dt}$ but I got stuck there.I need some help.

Comment: how was the covariant derivative defined? One possible definition is to orthogonally project $V^\prime$ to $TM$, if that is what you learned then this follows immediately from the definition...

Comment: if there exist a vector field $X$ such that $X(\gamma(t))=V(t)$ then $DV/dt=\bigtriangledown_(gamma)'(t)X$ where $\bigtriangledown $ is a connection.

Comment: What is $T_\gamma(t)M$?

Comment: But how is your connection defined? Probably either as the tangential projection of the ambient derivative (in which case this question is trivial) or as the Levi-Civita connection of the induced metric (in which case this reduces to proving that this coincides with the tangential projection - see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69066/tangential-component-of-a-riemannian-connection)

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis..I got it.Thanks. How one can show that on $S^2$ as a submanifold of $R^3$ a great circle parametrized by the arc length is a geodesic using the above result?

Comment: Show the velocity is normal to the sphere.

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis....I have tried to show that the velocity is orthogonal to the tangent space but I can't do that.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can write the vector field in local coordinates as $V=\sum_{j=1}^3 v_j\partial_j$. Thus $$\frac{DV}{dt}=(\overline{\nabla}_\overline{c'} \overline{V})^T=\left(\sum_k(\frac{dv_k}{dt}+\sum_{i,j}\Gamma_{i j}^k v_j \frac{dx_i}{dt})\partial_k \right)^T=\left(\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{dv_k}{dt}\partial_k\right)^T=\left(\frac{DV}{dt}\right)^T$$

The first equality is given by exercise $3$ from chap $2$ of manfredo and the third equality comes from the fact that the Christoffel symbols are zero in Euclidean spaces.

Now, note that you can write

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=(\frac{dV}{dt})^T+(\frac{dV}{dt})^N=\frac{DV}{dt}+(\frac{dV}{dt})^N$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Supose that $V$ is parallel. The above equation says that $\frac{dV}{dt}=(\frac{dV}{dt})^N$ (has only the normal component) which is perpendicular to $T_{c(t)}M$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now, suppose that $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is perpendicular to $T_{c(t)}M$.

As $\frac{DV}{dt}\in T_{c(t)}M$, it follows that

$$\langle \frac{dV}{dt},\frac{DV}{dt} \rangle =0 \iff \langle \frac{DV}{dt}+(\frac{dV}{dt})^N, \frac{DV}{dt} \rangle =0 \iff \langle \frac{DV}{dt} ,\frac{DV}{dt} \rangle =0 \iff \frac{DV}{dt}=0$$